# SQL Server Management Studio provider string MS Access 2016

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014, ms-access-2016

I need to make Access 2016 a linked server to Microsoft SQL Server 2014. I have downloaded and installed `AccessDatabaseEngine_x64`, and can find and select it in the "Provider" dropdown box on the "New Linked Server" dialog box, as seen in the image below. "Product Name" and "Data Source" are also entered correctly.

However, I cannot figure out what is the "Provider string" for Access 2016. Does anyone know what the string is or how to find it?

[image: New Linked Server dialog box]

Answer (score 0):

I have always found [this site](https://www.connectionstrings.com/) to be an invaluable resource.

Answer (score 0):

Data source: d:\folder\yourdatabase.accdb

Provider string:

Under Security, add a *Local Login*

Set *Remote User* to Admin and leave *Remote Password* empty.